# ASP.NET Core Redirect with data object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm making a Action method in a controller like following.

**In Model**

```
public class Model
{
    public string modelStr { get; set; }
}
```

**In Controller**

```
public IActionResult ActionMethod1(Model value) 
{
    return View(value); ---- debug point (1)
}

public IActionResult ActionMethod2(int pageKind)
{
    Model temp = new Model();

    if (pageKind == 1)
    {
        temp.modelStr = "Hi ASP.NET Core";
    }
    else
    {
        temp.modelStr = "error!";
    }

    return RedirectToAction("ActionMethod1", temp); ---- debug point (2)
}
```

And I access ActionMethod2 with `/Controller/ActionMethod2` in browser.
I expected `/Controller/ActionMethod1` will be called and its model `value` has value which is sent by `ActionMethod2`.

But if I debug it, 1) debuger do not stop at `debug point (2)` and at `debug point (1)` the `value` has no value, i.e `value.modelStr == null`.

How do value at `debug point (1)` get a value from `ActionMethod2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is caused by [parameter binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding).

The parameter `value` of `ActionMethod1` is type of `Model` class, this is a complex type, mvc will try to bind it's value from http body, the http request should be a POST request.

But `ActionMethod2` returns a `RedirectToAction` result,  the browser redirect to `ActionMethod1` with `GET`, and can not handle by `ActionMethod1`.

The answer is add `FromQueryAttribute` to the parameter `value` of `ActionMethod1`, tells mvc that `value` is bind from query string, like this:

```
public IActionResult ActionMethod1([FromQuery]Model value) 
{
    return View(value); ---- debug point (1)
}
```

Now `ActionMethod1` will handle GET request, and `ActionMethod2` can redirect to it.

Comment: It works! and your explanation is big help for me! thank you!!

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is not possible. However there are work-arounds. One common approach is to add the data to the TempData dictionary and retrieve it in the other method:

```
public IActionResult ActionMethod1()
{
    var value = (Model)TempData["model"];

    return View(value);
}

public IActionResult ActionMethod2(int pageKind)
{
    Model temp = new Model();

    if (pageKind == 1)
    {
        temp.modelStr = "Hi ASP.NET Core";
    }
    else
    {
        temp.modelStr = "error!";
    }

    TempData["model"] = temp;

    return RedirectToAction("ActionMethod1");
}
```

Alternatively, are you sure you even need to actually redirect the user? You could always just call the method directly:

```
public IActionResult ActionMethod1(Model value)
{
    return View(value);
}

public IActionResult ActionMethod2(int pageKind)
{
    Model temp = new Model();

    if (pageKind == 1)
    {
        temp.modelStr = "Hi ASP.NET Core";
    }
    else
    {
        temp.modelStr = "error!";
    }

    return ActionMethod1(temp);
}
```